# Can you form a list with elements which are terms from an equation?

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a command that takes an equation as an input and creates an output with a list of terms in the original equation? Something like:

```
Input: Foo[ (1+a) x+ (2.5-b) y^2+ 3 c z^{1.3}]

Output: { (1+a) x ,  (2.5-b) y^2 ,  3 c z^{1.3} }
```

Comment: You can expand your equation and then apply `List`.

Comment: `Variables`, e.g. `Variables[x^3 + 6 x^2 y + 3 x y z + x z^2 + 1]` yields `{x, y, z}`

Comment: If you want monomials there is e.g. `MonomialList[a x + b y^2 + 3 c z^{1.3}]` yielding `{{1. a x, 1. b y^2, 3. c z^(13/10)}}`

Comment: Hi guys, thank you very much for your help so far. Unfortunately I have had to update the question as I try your suggestions and see what additional flexibility I else I need.

Comment: So you need `List @@ ((1 + a) x + (2.5 - b) y^2 + 3 c z^1.3)` returning `{(1 + a) x, (2.5 - b) y^2, 3 c z^1.3}`

Comment: @Spawn1701D - I see what you are saying now. Apply[List,%] does the trick. If you want to write this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Artes - your suggestion works too- thanks so much!

Comment: Huh, I can't seem to see an `==` sign anywhere. Where's the "equation"?

Answer (score 7):

What you are asking to do, it seems, is to replace the `Plus` Head, with the `List` Head. The `Apply` function, shorthanded as `@@`, will do what you want:

```
Input: expr = Foo[a + b + c];
```

Now we can get just the `a+b+c` with `First`:

```
Input: expr2 = First@expr;
```

Check out `FullForm` to get rid of shorthanded notation:

```
Input: FullForm[expr2]
Output: Plus[a,b,c]
```

And finally, we can turn `Plus` into `List` with `Apply`:

```
Input: List@@expr2
Output: {a,b,c}
```

All in one line:

```
Input: List@@First[Foo[a+b+c]]
```

Comment: I am fairly certain that `Foo` was given as the example of the function itself, meaning that `Foo[a + b + c]` should directly evaluate to `{a, b, c}`.  Nevertheless +1.

Answer (score 5):

Examining the structure of the expression with `TreeForm`

```
TreeForm@Foo[(1 + a) x + (2.5 - b) y^2 + 3 c z^{1.3}]
```

[image: TreeForm@Foo[(1 + a) x + (2.5 - b) y^2 + 3 c z^{1.3}]]

shows us another way:

```
Level[Foo[(1 + a) x + (2.5 - b) y^2 + 3 c z^{1.3}], {3}]

(* {(1 + a) x, (2.5 - b) y^2, 3 c z^1.3} *)
```

(Simply count the depth of the function arguments from the `Head` of the expression.)