# Expression manipulation: Explode sums and products?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I wonder if the functionality exists to explode a sum, or product? What I mean by that is the following. Imagine, you have input data

```
data = a + b c - d e f ;
```

Is there a function `ExplodeSum` such that

```
res1 = ExplodeSum[data]
*out*
{a,b c,-d e f}
```

is the result (arbitrary but fixed order)? And then, is there a function, such that

```
res2 = ExplodeProduct[ res1[[2]] ]
*out*
{b,c}
```

is the result? If yes, please let me know how those functions are actually called. Or maybe one can implement these functions? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Related: [(2449)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/121) (see item #3).  Also related: [(55597)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55597/121)

Comment: I found a similar question: [(25338)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25338/121).  Unless someone argues for this question being unique I shall be closing it as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the solutions! My question has been answered. (@Mr.Wizard: The problem with these kind of questions is that one does not know exactly what to search for. So it is easier to ask again. - Now, I'm sure the next person searching for "explode sum" will find this question here, so it is not all in vain.)

Comment: I did not mean to suggest that you should not have asked this Question.  While it is always appreciated if one searches first I am fully aware that even extensive searching may not reveal existing questions that can be answered in a similar way.  You are correct that your question, even though closed now, will help people find the answer they need, here or in the linked Q&A.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
res1 = data /. Plus -> List
```

> ```
>  {a, b c, -d e f}
> ```

```
res1[[2]] /. Times -> List
```

> ```
> {b, c}
> ```

As a function:

```
explodeOp[expr_, op_] := expr /. op -> List
```

Then:

```
res1 = explodeOp[data, Plus];
explodeOp[res1[[2]], Times]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
List @@ (a + b c - d e ff)
```

Output is

```
{a, b c, -d e ff}
```

Likewise, to explode a product, do this:

```
List @@ %[[2]]
```

Output is

```
{b, c}
```

This works because `List @@` deletes the head of `(a + b c - d e ff)`, which is `Plus`, and replaces it with list, giving `List[a, b c, -d e ff]` (and similar for product explosion).

Answer (score 1):

```
Cases[a + b c - d e f, _]
(*{a, b c, -d e f}*)

Level[a + b c - d e f, 1]
(*{a, b c, -d e f}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set `Part` `0` of input list to `List`:

```
ClearAll[data, a, b, c, d, e, f];
data = a + b c - d e f;

data2=data;
data2[[0]] = List; 
data2
(* {a, b c, -d e f} *)

data2 = data[[2]];
data2[[0]] = List;
data2
(* {b,c} *)
```

or, define a function that `List`ifies the `Head`s:

```
ClearAll[lF1];
lF1 = Function[{h}, h[[0]] = List; h, HoldFirst];

data2 = data;
{lF1@data2, lF1@data2[[2]]}
(* {{a, b c, -d e f}, {b, c}}  *)
```

You can also use: `MapAt` or `ReplacePart` to change the `Head`s to `List`:

```
ClearAll[lF2];
lF2 = MapAt[List &, #, {0}] &;

data2 = data;
{lF2@data2, lF2@data2[[2]]}
(* {{a,b c,-d e f},{b,c}} *)

data2 = data;
{ReplacePart[data2, 0 -> List], ReplacePart[data2[[2]], 0 -> List]}
(* {{a, b c, -d e f}, {b, c}} *)
```